# Excel next number formula

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

I would like a formula for the following if anyone can be of help:

in subsequent cells going down a column i would like every 4th cell to increase by 8, and then each of the next three cells to decrease by 1 each time: i.e) **11**,10,9,8,**19**,18,17,16,**27**,26,25,24...

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SU! What have you tried, Emily?

Comment: I have tried simply dragging down, but that was as expected no good. And i tried INT((ROW()+2)/4)+8 but that wasn't right

Comment: Do you have the alternative to have a second column with a consecutive next to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your starting number in A1.

Then in the cell A2 put:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($A$1:A1)+8,A1-1)
```

Then copy/drag the formula down

[image]

---

Starting with B2, formula in B3:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($B$2:B2)+8,B2-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Edit: I've got it working! Thank you very much

Comment: Can i use a similar formula for repeating numbers? Ie) say if i wanted 9,12,15,18 repeating over and over down a column?

Comment: New Question = New Post, You could do something like @Mate suggested.  But if you wanted one formula it would be different.

Comment: Ok, sorry - new to superuser! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @EmilyG also please mark the formula you used as correct.  You can only mark one, by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Hi, turns out what you have suggested isn't working completely when I tried to start from B3... could you suggest where my edit has made an error please? I put 11 into B2 and =IF(MOD(ROW($3:$3),4)=0,MAX($B$3:B3)+8,B3-1) into B3 however this gives simply 11,10,9,8,7,6,5....

Comment: You would only change the A1 to B2: `=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($B$2:B2)+8,B2-1)`

Comment: Hi ,thats just returning #VALUE! ...

Comment: Sometime the comments adds weird characters to the formula.  retype the formula directly, not copy and paste.  But the formula works for me

Comment: Hi, have typed it and still not working... thank you for trying though.

Comment: Did you see my edit.  What is the formula you are trying?

Comment: I have tried =IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($B$2:B2)+8,B2-1) and multiple variations of it, as i am trying to have the first number, 11 in B3 and have the sequence follow from there i.e.: B3=11, B4=10, B5=9, B6=8, B7=19...

Comment: So in B3 put 11, then in B4: `=IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($B$3:B3)+8,B3-1)`

Comment: =IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),4)=0,MAX($B$3:B3)+8,B3-1) Still doesn't work... its returned a mixture of numbers and some other cells from my spreadsheet. Beginning to lose hope haha

Answer (score 1):

"Simplest" way is to type 11,10,9,8 in first four cells, then use this formula: `=A2+8`

[image]